# how to redirect TCP packages to a proxy without losing the original destination?

Tags: linux, redirect, tcp, iptables

im trying to redirect tcp packages to my proxy but i lose the original ip destination in the process. because of that my proxy cant start a connection to
the original destination. my setup looks like this:

i have a normal tls linux server which i call C.
i have a man-in-the-middle proxy on my linux pc called B.
A is an android amulator in which a tls connection to C is started. A doesnt
use http or https. it just sends random data over tls.

i want A to connect to B and B to connect to C.
inside the android emulator i put in a iptables rule to redirect the tcp packages to my proxy server and it works. the only problem is that my 
proxy doesnt know the destination ip of the original destination. do i need
to somehow add a header to the packages or how would i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The original target IP address is permanently lost if you redirect a packet to another machine since in this case the target IP of the packet needs to be replaced. There is no way to attach some information about the original IP address to the packet.

The situation is different if you redirect just to some proxy on the same machine. In this case the proxy could retrieve the original destination by calling `getsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, SO_ORIGINAL_DST)` (on Linux, other systems might differ) since it is still known by the OS kernel.

Thus you need to make sure that you do the redirect on the same system as the proxy resides. For this the proxy system must be in the routing path to receive the packet, for example by setting it as the default gateway.